# Workbox cache strategies not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, web-worker

I am building a react app using create-react-app and [react-app-rewired-workbox](https://github.com/davejm/react-app-rewire-workbox) to work with workbox.

I want to use networkOnly strategy of workbox but somehow it's not working. Service worker is responding with cache even if i make network offline

I tried other strategies also but workbox is only using it's default behaviour and responding with cache first.

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting()));
self.addEventListener('activate', event => event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim()));

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest);

workbox.routing.registerRoute("/", new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly());
```

here is how it is behaving
precached all the routes
[image: precached all the routes]

network is offline
[image: network is offline]

precaching is responding in offline
[image: precaching is responding in offline]

service worker is handling the request
[image: service worker is handling the request]

what i am expecting is that when i am using networkOnly strategy it should not respond with cache. Workbox is also not logging the strategy it is using when responding to any request.

Answer (score 0):

According to precache option, you need to remove this line, because the routes response to Manifest precache.

```js
workbox.core.setLogLevel(workbox.core.LOG_LEVELS.debug);

self.addEventListener('install', event => event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting()));
self.addEventListener('activate', event => event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim()));


// We need this in Webpack plugin (refer to swSrc option): https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#full_injectmanifest_config
// REMOVE THIS:
//workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest);

workbox.routing.registerRoute("/", workbox.strategies.networkOnly());
```